# Formatting with echo command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, eval, echo

The actual situation is a bit complicated, but the issue I'm running into is that I have an **echo** command within an **eval** command. Like so:

```
$ eval echo 'keep   my     spacing'
keep my spacing
$ echo 'keep   my     spacing'
keep   my     spacing
```

I was wondering how I could keep **eval** from stripping my spacing so that the first command prints out the same message as the second...

---

Here's a closer example to what's actually going on:

```
$ eval `python -c 'print "echo \"keep    my     spacing\""'`
keep my spacing
```

Answer (score 1):

`eval echo "'keep   my     spacing'"`

Answer (score 1):

```
eval "echo 'keep   my     spacing'"
keep   my     spacing
```

If that does not work for you, please explain more about the actual situation.

Comment: OK. So I have a Python script that's setting up modifications to the environment...aliases, environment variables, ... That part of it needs to be evaluated with eval and works fine. At the end of that I also want to print out some messages. Before running through eval things are fine and spaced nicely. eval strips all my formatting and makes a long line of text... It does keep newlines though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the fault of `eval`:

```
`python -c 'print "echo \"keep    my     spacing\""'`
```

prints

```
"keep my spacing"
```

Instead you could do this:

```
python -c 'print "echo \"keep    my     spacing\""' | bash
```

This prints

```
keep    my     spacing
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem (in the python example) is that the command substitution (the backquoted expression) isn't protected by quotes.  To fix, put double-quotes around it (and to make the quotes nest better, use `$()` instead of backquotes):

```
eval "$(python -c 'print "echo \"keep    my     spacing\""')"
```

Answer (score 0):

or consider printf -v

Answer (score 0):

```
$ . <(python -c 'print "echo \"keep    my     spacing\""')
keep    my     spacing
```